# Nodemon no such file or directory problem

Tags: npm, nodemon

So I've gone through fixing npm permissions, created a new hidden folder called npm-package. After that, I tried installing nodemon globally but it gives me the following error when I try to run it.

```
$ nodemon app
bash: /usr/local/bin/nodemon: No such file or directory
```

I've looked at other SO threads but most of them are referencing a "command not found" error rather than this issue.

I have also tried other suggestions on SO threads, using
 `sudo npm install -g nodemon` and I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling. So far none of those have worked. Any ideas?

EDIT: As it turns out, I also got a command not found error when I tried running nodemon on my terminal. For some reason I was getting a different error in VS Code. So this did turn out to be a duplicate, but has a different solution to what has been provided on other SO threads. Sorry about that!

Comment: install nodemon to your project as devellopment module,rather than trying to install globally.

Comment: How do I do that? Is it just npm install nodemon in the project directory? If so, I tried that too

Comment: For running it locally you can use npx nodemon

Comment: Tell me if this works for you sudo npm install -g --force nodemon

Comment: Looks like it installed fine, but I got the same error afterwards

Comment: What error please show the error

Comment: `bash: /usr/local/bin/nodemon: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run `brew doctor`, look at the warnings and fix them. It said that I had unlinked kegs, so I had to look at another SO thread to fix that. That didn't fix the issue though, so I went to the npm site to fix permissions (the one that tells you to `mkdir npm-global` or something along those lines). Once you do this, you have to reinstall nodemon with `npm install -g nodemon`, and when you run nodemon it should show something like:

`Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]
See "nodemon --help" for more.`